# SPARQL - find and/or filter relations between 3 persons

Tags: filter, sparql, protege

I have an ontology (built in Protege) with several Family members. There can be good (yellow) or bad (orange) relationships between persons like in this image:

[image: good and bad family relationships]

All good and bad relations are symmetric!

I'm trying to find all "triangle" relationships between all persons. The problem is I get too many results, and I can't find a way to reduce the result with the FILTER function.

My SPARQL query:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
{
     ?p1 g:hasGoodRel ?p2 . 

     OPTIONAL {?p1 g:hasBadRel  ?p3 . }
     OPTIONAL {?p2 g:hasBadRel  ?p3 . }
    }
}
```

The result is this:

```
:D  :C  :E  
:D  :D  :E  
:C  :D  :E  <-- 
:C  :D  :A  
:C  :B  :E  
:C  :B  :A  <--
:B  :C
```

I just want this 2 results (triangles)

```
:A  :B  :C  
:C  :D  :E
```

I tried different Filter combinations like this

```
 FILTER(?p1 != ?p2) 
 FILTER(?p1 != ?p3)
 FILTER(?p1 < ?p2)
```

But never got my desired result... I hope some one can point me in the right direction.

//EDIT
Here is the example as turtle

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#hasBadRel
:hasBadRel rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
           rdfs:subPropertyOf owl:topObjectProperty ;
           rdf:type owl:SymmetricProperty .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#hasGoodRel
:hasGoodRel rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
            rdfs:subPropertyOf owl:topObjectProperty ;
            rdf:type owl:SymmetricProperty .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#Person
:Person rdf:type owl:Class .


#################################################################
#    Individuals
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#A
:A rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :Person ;
   :hasBadRel :B ,
              :C ,
              :G .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#B
:B rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :Person ;
   :hasBadRel :A ;
   :hasGoodRel :C ,
               :G .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#C
:C rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :Person ;
   :hasBadRel :A ,
              :E ;
   :hasGoodRel :B ,
               :D .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#D
:D rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :Person ;
   :hasBadRel :E ;
   :hasGoodRel :C .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#E
:E rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :Person ;
   :hasBadRel :C ,
              :D .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#F
:F rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :Person ;
   :hasBadRel :C ,
              :D .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#G
:G rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :Person ;
   :hasBadRel :A ;
   :hasGoodRel :B .


###  Generated by the OWL API (version 4.2.8.20170104-2310) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi
```

### Update 2 ###

Here are the results of my second test based on this graph:

[image: Test graph]

Sparql query by AKSW

```
:A  :B  :E  
:A  :B  :F  
:A  :C  :E  
:B  :D  :E
:C  :D  :E
```

and the query by Stanislav Kralin

```
:A  :B  :E  
:A  :B  :F
:A  :C  :E  
:C  :D  :E
```

The difference is only :B  :D  :E

So both queries are working as intended. Many thanks again.

If someone wants to test this graph, here is the ontology

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#hasBadRel
:hasBadRel rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
           rdfs:subPropertyOf owl:topObjectProperty .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#hasGoodRel
:hasGoodRel rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
            rdfs:subPropertyOf owl:topObjectProperty .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#Person
:Person rdf:type owl:Class .


#################################################################
#    Individuals
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#A
:A rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :Person ;
   :hasBadRel :E ;
   :hasGoodRel :B ,
               :C .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#B
:B rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :Person ;
   :hasBadRel :D ,
              :E ;
   :hasGoodRel :A .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#C
:C rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :Person ;
   :hasGoodRel :E .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#D
:D rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :Person ;
   :hasBadRel :B ;
   :hasGoodRel :C .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#E
:E rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :Person ;
   :hasBadRel :A ,
              :B ,
              :D .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#F
:F rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :Person ;
   :hasBadRel :A ,
              :B .


###  Generated by the OWL API (version 4.2.8.20170104-2310) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi
```

Comment: It should have at least one bad or one good relation. So good good bad OR bad bad good is possible

Comment: I added the bad and good tripels in turtle.

Comment: @MarkMiller I can test it for you

Comment: I'm wondering if we both have the same idea :D See my answer and feel free to add an alternative solution :D

Comment: @theChaosCoder, don't you mean *"it should have at least one bad **and** one good relation"*? "Good-good-good" should be possible?

Comment: yes correct, my bad

Comment: @theChaosCoder What is correct? `good - good - good` is allowed? Or not allowed?

Comment: No, it is like  Stanislav Kralin said at least one bad and one good + (one bad or good)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45633265/sparql-find-and-or-filter-relations-between-3-persons#comment78228776_45633265), relationships should be "heterogeneous", i. e. both good and bad relations should be present in a triangle. Thus, your query could be:

```sql
PREFIX pref: <http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?s1 ?s2 ?s3
    WHERE { 
           {
           ?s1 pref:hasGoodRel|^pref:hasGoodRel ?s2 . 
           ?s1 pref:hasGoodRel|^pref:hasGoodRel ?s3 . 
           ?s2 pref:hasBadRel|^pref:hasBadRel ?s3 . 
           }
           UNION
           {
           ?s1 pref:hasBadRel|^pref:hasBadRel ?s2 . 
           ?s1 pref:hasBadRel|^pref:hasBadRel ?s3 . 
           ?s2 pref:hasGoodRel|^pref:hasGoodRel ?s3 .
           }
           FILTER (str(?s2) < str(?s3))
          }
```

The idea is that there are only two kinds of 'situations': 'two good, one bad' and 'two bad, one good'.

In every 'situation', `?s1` is bound univocally, whereas `?s2` and `?s3` are not. Then the `FILTER` clause forces univocal bindings for `?s2` and `?s3`.

---

Without using `UNION`, it looks difficult to figure out appropriate `FILTER` condition (check that the condition from AKSW's answer is inappropriate in this case). However it is possible.

```sql
PREFIX pref: <http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?s1 ?s2 ?s3 WHERE { 
    ?s1 pref:hasGoodRel|^pref:hasGoodRel ?s2 . 
    ?s1 pref:hasBadRel|^pref:hasBadRel ?s3 . 
    ?s2 pref:hasBadRel|^pref:hasBadRel|pref:hasGoodRel|^pref:hasGoodRel ?s3 . 
    BIND ((str(?s1) > str(?s2)) AS ?x) .
    BIND ((str(?s2) > str(?s3)) AS ?y) .
    BIND ((str(?s1) < str(?s3)) AS ?z) .
    FILTER (( ?x || ?y ) && ( ?x || ?z ) && ( ?y || ?z ))
    } ORDER BY ASC(?s1)
```

Here below complete RDF test data. A correct query should return 12 results: exactly one result for every letter A–L.

```
@prefix  pref: <http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#> 

pref:A1 pref:hasGoodRel pref:A2 .
pref:A1 pref:hasBadRel pref:A3 .
pref:A2 pref:hasBadRel pref:A3 .

pref:B1 pref:hasBadRel pref:B2 .
pref:B1 pref:hasGoodRel pref:B3 .
pref:B2 pref:hasBadRel pref:B3 .

pref:C1 pref:hasGoodRel pref:C2 .
pref:C1 pref:hasBadRel pref:C3 .
pref:C2 pref:hasBadRel pref:C3 .

pref:D1 pref:hasBadRel pref:D2 .
pref:D1 pref:hasGoodRel pref:D3 .
pref:D2 pref:hasBadRel pref:D3 .

pref:E1 pref:hasBadRel pref:E2 .
pref:E1 pref:hasBadRel pref:E3 .
pref:E2 pref:hasGoodRel pref:E3 .

pref:F1 pref:hasBadRel pref:F2 .
pref:F1 pref:hasBadRel pref:F3 .
pref:F2 pref:hasGoodRel pref:F3 .

#################

pref:G1 pref:hasBadRel pref:G2 .
pref:G1 pref:hasGoodRel pref:G3 .
pref:G2 pref:hasGoodRel pref:G3 .

pref:H1 pref:hasGoodRel pref:H2 .
pref:H1 pref:hasBadRel pref:H3 .
pref:H2 pref:hasGoodRel pref:H3 .

pref:I1 pref:hasBadRel pref:I2 .
pref:I1 pref:hasGoodRel pref:I3 .
pref:I2 pref:hasGoodRel pref:I3 .

pref:J1 pref:hasGoodRel pref:J2 .
pref:J1 pref:hasBadRel pref:J3 .
pref:J2 pref:hasGoodRel pref:J3 .

pref:K1 pref:hasGoodRel pref:K2 .
pref:K1 pref:hasGoodRel pref:K3 .
pref:K2 pref:hasBadRel pref:K3 .

pref:L1 pref:hasGoodRel pref:L2 .
pref:L1 pref:hasGoodRel pref:L3 .
pref:L2 pref:hasBadRel pref:L3 .
```

To be honest, I have generated all possible `FILTER` conditions of particular kind using <s>Wolfram Cloud</s> Mathematica and then check them semi-automatically.

```
Do[Print[BooleanMinimize[BooleanFunction[i, {x,y,z}]]], {i, 1, 255, 1}]
```

Comment: I guess the solution by AKWS could be seen as a more generic approach. Thank you for your solution. I will make some more tests later and post the results here with some visual helpers .

Comment: Your Wolfram link returns "Sorry, you do not have permission to access this item."

Answer (score 2):

My idea would be to use SPARQL 1.1 property paths with the pattern `:p1|:p2` and check for paths between three nodes `n1 - n2 - n3 - n1`:

```sql
PREFIX g: <http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#> 
SELECT *
WHERE {
     ?p1 g:hasGoodRel|g:hasBadRel ?p2.
     ?p2 g:hasGoodRel|g:hasBadRel ?p3.
     ?p3 g:hasGoodRel|g:hasBadRel ?p1

     FILTER(str(?p1) < str(?p2) && str(?p2) < str(?p3))            
}
```

Note, my solution assumes that paths using just one of the relations are allowed. For example

```
n1 --hasGoodRel--> n2 --hasGoodRel--> n3 --hasGoodRel--> n1
```

### Update

In order to consider undirected graphs, we have to use an additional property path expression `p|^p` which considers incoming and outgoing edges via `p`

```sql
PREFIX g: <http://www.semanticweb.org/anato/ontologies/2017/7/untitled-ontology-186#> 
SELECT DISTINCT *
WHERE {
     ?p1 (g:hasGoodRel|^g:hasGoodRel)|(g:hasBadRel|^g:hasBadRel) ?p2.
     ?p2 (g:hasGoodRel|^g:hasGoodRel)|(g:hasBadRel|^g:hasBadRel) ?p3.
     ?p3 (g:hasGoodRel|^g:hasGoodRel)|(g:hasBadRel|^g:hasBadRel) ?p1

     FILTER(str(?p1) < str(?p2) && str(?p2) < str(?p3))            
}
```

#### Output

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| p1  | p2  | p3  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  :A |  :B |  :C |
|  :A |  :B |  :G |
|  :C |  :D |  :E |
|  :C |  :D |  :F |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: A very nice solution! I added some more Persons and it still works as intended. Many Thanks

Comment: Interesting. I was just going to say { ?fm1 :hasGoodRel ?fm2 ; :hasBadRel ?fm3 . ?fm2 (:hasGoodRel|:hasBadRel) ?fm3 }

Comment: Yours are working too, but with some redundant results like ABC ACB

Comment: @AKSW I know I said symmetric relations ^_^ But could your approach also catch Persons with non symetric relations with some modifications? Like when one Person A hates the relationship of Person B+C (B+C don't care)

This would be 

:F rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :Person ;
   :hasBadRel :C ,
              :D .

Comment: @MarkMiller Maybe I didn't understand the task correctly, but I was thinking that a circle of length 3 in the graph has to be found, such that each edge is either `hasGoodRel` or `hasBadRel`. I'm not sure whether it's necessary that both relations are used or whether it's also a valid solution if all are connect via only one of the relations.

Comment: @theChaosCoder Can you please add this to your question also with some example? I'm not sure if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Good questions, both of you. I wrote my query quickly while riding the train. I am confused about one thing... ChaosCoder is talking now about the way A feels about the between B and C. How is that modelled in the data? What you've shown so far is only binary relations between people, not the attitudes they hold about other relationships.

Comment: Right. Then we would talk about reification.

Comment: I updated the ontology. Person F hasBadRel to C and D, but C and D have no relations to F. It visually forms a triangle (special case).  You could actually interpreted this as a "low form" of reification. But I don't use reification in my ontology.

Comment: Here is some Context https://www.genopro.com/articles/bush-family.png I*m trying to build a genogram ontology and need sparql to find some "triangles" among Family members. Most of the time there are symmetric 
 emotional relations. But im some cases non symmetrical are used to if A hates B but B don't hate A back. I hope this is not too confusing :)

Comment: Genogramm = Family Family Tree + Emotional Relations

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you need, but I added a query that considers undirected graphs. `C,D,F` and `A,B,G` are additional solutions now

Comment: As far as I can see (test) here, this is exactly that I need. Thank you very much again for your solution.